# pmap over lists of differing length

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to determine how I might use the `dplyr` `pmap` function applied to lists of differing length.

A very simple example of what I would like to do would be the following

```
list_1 <- list(1, 2, 3)

list_2 <- list(1, 2)

list_3 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)


pmap(list(list_1, list_2, list_3), ~ ..1 + ..2 + ..3)
```

Where the result above would be a list of length `length(list_1) * length(list_2) * length(list_3)` containing the sum of all combinations of the 3 lists

My actual application is a bit more complicated in that I am trying to fit `glm` models where `list_1` is the response `list_2` and `list_3` being other `glm` function inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pmap` doesn't generate all combinations, it just applies a function to the first element of each list element, then the second, etc. You need expand.grid (or similar)

```
l.combs <- expand.grid(list_1, list_2, list_3)
l.combs[] <- lapply(l.combs, unlist)
rowSums(l.combs)
```

Or with `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
l.combs <- expand.grid(list_1, list_2, list_3)
pmap(l.combs, ~ ..1 + ..2 + ..3)
```

Edit: Here's an example with `glm` that "works" but is obviously nonsense statistically

```
list_1 <- replicate(3, runif(10), simplify = F)

list_2 <- replicate(2, runif(10), simplify = F)

list_3 <- replicate(5, runif(10), simplify = F)

l.combs <- expand.grid(list_1, list_2, list_3)
pmap(l.combs, ~ glm(..1 ~ ..2 + ..3))
```

Comment: Would that `pmap` result actually work with a more complete example where lm or glm was being used?

Comment: It works with the example in the question. Hopefully that should clarify how to use pmap after expandind.grid. Not sure what they mean exactly with the glm stuff

Comment: I realize that the questioner didn't actually provide a full example of his target use for this.

Comment: Added an example where `pmap` uses `glm`

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't throw an error, so: Bravo! (But I wonder if it works with names of vectors?)